# SSL certificate paths in a virtual host

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I've recently purchased a wildcard SSL certificate for my domain, generated the CSR, and everything has been sent through OK.

My question is quite straightforward, but following this - http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_apache.php, I can't make any sense of what to match to what.

Basically - I have 5 files:

```
- gs_intermediate_ca.crt
- gs_root.pem
- mydomain.com.crt
- intermediate.pem
- *.mydomain.com.key
```

The Values:

```
SSLCACertificateFile = ?
SSLCertificateChainFile = ?
SSLCertificateFile = mydomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile = ?
```

I'm new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Edit >>
Using the Answers below! Cheers,

I'm now receiving the following errors:

```
[error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
[error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

My vHost now looks like so:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.key/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/ca.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
```

Any idea where these errors can be coming from - is there a check I can run on the .crt file?

Kind regards

Comment: `*.mydomain.com.key` - is that really a file name? If so I'd remove `*.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doc is definitely confusing. My guess:

```
SSLCACertificateFile = /path/to/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile = /path/to/chain_file
SSLCertificateFile = /path/to/mydomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile = /path/to/mydomain.com.wildcard.key
```

You should put all files outside the DocumentRoot and protect them with ownership/permissions. (I usually store certs in /etc/apache2/ssl and set ownership to root:root, permissions to 400.)

EDIT: You should download a combined chain ("bundle") file here:
http://www.globalsign.com/support/intermediate-root-install.php

Scroll to GlobalSign Root Bundle Certificates.

Answer (score 3):

```
SSLCertificateFile mydomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile mydomain.com.key
```

For `SSLCertificateChainFile`, you'll make a new file.  Combine the intermediate and root certificates into one file formatted like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(intermediate certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(root certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And point `SSLCertificateChainFile` at that.

Comment: +1 Essentially the same solution, but alternate method, without a ton of edits :-)